# Sudo Privileges required in Azure Cloud Shell to mkdir

Tags: azure, ansible

I'm trying to run the following command in Azure Cloud Shell

```
sudo mkdir /etc/ansible
```

However, I keep on getting the following error:

```
bash: sudo: command not found
```

I did some research and discovered Azure Cloud Shell doesn't permit Sudo access, and Microsoft Azure states the following:

*Permissions are set as regular users without sudo access. Any installation outside your $Home directory is not persisted.*

However, when do PWD I'm in more $Home directory:

```
peter@Azure:~/ansible$ pwd
/home/peter/ansible
```

Can someone let me know how to get around this limitation?

Comment: Just as an update, when I try to mkdir without the sudo command I get the following error: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/etc/ansible’: Permission denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, it it **not** possible.

It's a by design behavior, that machine that provides your Cloud shell session is temporary.

Permissions are set as regular users without sudo access.

You can't `mkdir` in `/etc`:

[image]

Cloud shell not equal to a virtual machine, you can run Azure CLI command on it, but Cloud shell is **recycled** after your session is inactive for 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known [Bash limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/limitations#bash-limitations).

**Note:** *Permissions are set as regular users without sudo access. Any installation outside your `$Home` directory is not persisted.*

You can only create directories inside the `$Home`.

**Example:**

[image]